# Using array implode for building insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am following tutorials for user registration. This is what I am trying to build query using implode:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $registration_data= array(
                    'username'      =>   $_POST['username'], 
                    'password'      =>   $_POST['password'], 
                    'password_again' =>   $_POST['password_again'], 
                    'first_name'    =>   $_POST['first_name'], 
                    'last_name'     =>   $_POST['last_name'],
                    'email'         =>   $_POST['email']
                );     

                register_user($registration_data);

        }

function register_user($registration_data){
        global $connect; 
        $data=implode(',', $registration_data).'}';
        $fields= implode(",", array_keys($registration_data));
```

Now I have to build query like this

```
$query=INSERT INTO users ($fields) VALUES($data);

//  I want data to be formated like this '{$username}', '{$password}',
```

How can I do it in above mentioned implode functions,

*Note:* I am just following some basic tutorials so not worried about PDO/ injections etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around all the data values before you implode them:

```
$data = implode(',', array_map(function($x) {
    return "'" . $x . "'";
}, $registration_data));
$fields = implode(',', array_keys($registration_data));
$query = "INSERT INTO users ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
```

Comment: so this anonymous function gonna receive array ? should i add these { }   also ?

Comment: SQL doesn't use `{ }`, so I don't know why you would want to add that.

Comment: Read the documentation of `array_map`. The anonymous function is called for each element of the array, and it returns an array containing the results.

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you are just learning on how to do this, you should learn to do them right from the beginning.

You really don't need to use `implode()` with prepared statements. Just use `PDO::prepare()` and pass the array to `PDOStatement::execute`. Pseudo code is along the lines of:

```
$registration_data= array(
    ':username'      =>   $_POST['username'], 
    ':password'      =>   $_POST['password'], 
    ':password_agai' =>   $_POST['password_again'], 
    ':first_name'    =>   $_POST['first_name'], 
    ':last_name'     =>   $_POST['last_name'],
    ':email'         =>   $_POST['email']
);     

$sql='INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (:username, :password, :password_agai, :first_name, :last_name, :email);';
$qry=$yourpdoconn->prepare($sql);
$qry->execute($registration_data);
```

Please note that you still need to handle your errors and everything else, but that's the gist of it. `mysqli_*` can do the same with prepared statements so you aren't necessarily stuck with PDO either.